# Revit: Attempt to modify the model outside of transaction

Tags: c#, revit-api

When I create default rebar bar type, I met this error: "Attempt to modify the model outside of transaction." Can you explain for me?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to modify the Revit Model database, you have to wrap your code into a transaction:

```
using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "My transaction")) 
{ 
   t.Start();
   // Your code 
   t.Commit(); 
}
```

Even better with a try-catch.
If you are using non-modal form, you have to create ExternalEvent on top of that.
If that is the case, I can only recommand [this excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHMwd4U_Lrs&list=PLFCkCJ3EkCJ6irc8-QwipB3TTsvlz2_xa).
Good luck,

François

Comment: It's not enough for me to edit it myself (6 characters is the minimum for an edit), but there are two semicolons missing: one after `t.Start()`, and one after `t.Commit()`.
Thanks for the answer Robb, I found it useful :)